# number of combinations/permutations

Tags: permutations, combinations

if I have $n$ **drawers** and in each **drawer** I can only have `1` **pen** *or* `1` **pencil**

for example if i have $3$ **drawers**
the possible combinations are

1. (pen,pen,pen)
2. (pen,pen,pencil)
3. (pen,pencil,pencil)
4. (pencil,pencil,pencil)

so $p = 4$

is $p$ always equals $n+1$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: Sure.  If you have n drawers then count the number of pens: you can have $0, 1, 2, ..., n$, so $n+1$ options.  Once you know the number of pens, the numnber of pencils is determined by subtraction.

Comment: You forgot some...
(pen,pencil,pen) - (pencil,pen,pen) - (pencil,pen,pencil) - (pencil,pencil,pen) ...

So you get $8 = 2^3$

Comment: I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that the OP was ignoring order. Agreed this needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order does matter, then there is just two choices for each drawer, so there are $2^n$ possibilities for $n$ drawers. In this case there would be $8$, then.

If order does *not* matter, then you can think, if you have $n$ writing utensils, you could have $0$ pencils (and therefore $n$ pens), $1$ pencil (and therefore $n-1$ pens), 2 pencils, etc., up to $n$ pencils and no pens. This is $n+1$ options.